# How to Enable Wireless on Nexus 7

Tags: installation, wireless, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

How do I enable Wireless on my Nexus 7 running Ubuntu on Nexus7?

When I click the Network Manager Icon its not showing any available networks.

Comment: What type of network environment do you have? We've never seen this in over 90 installs in a variety of environments but it's possible we missed something.

Comment: Did suggestion resolve this?  **Close !?**

Answer (score 3):

Wireless appears to not always work on the initial boot after the Nexus 7 Install completes just reboot the device and networks should be available.

Comment: Disabling and re-enabling the wireless also seems to help.